# JavaScript - dynamic link depending on multiple DropDown Selections or Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

New to Javascript. Here is the story:
I need to create a dynamic link to redirect to one of the 6 different courses, depending on the options chosen by the user. This can be done via 3 dropdown menus or via 3 sets of checkboxes:

img. 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieNEq.png

or

img. 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8li5j.png

I tried to combine codes from several examples from stackoverflow, but it's a mess... Any idea is highly appreciated.

[edit 06.04.2015]

Thanks for your suggestions, but the story is a little more complicated:

1. The links are fixed, i.e. they are quite complicated to write it via a "generate" function (they are something like: base_url + id_1 + base_url_2 + id_2 + base_url_3)
2. There are 6 different courses, each one with its own link:
   a) regular user - in English 
     b) regular user - in German 
   c) user with access to confidential data - in English 
   d) user with access to confidential data - in German 
   e) user manager - in English 
   f) user manager - in German

To select the proper course, you would need to meet criteria from more than one form. I think there should be a lot of "if" statements in place in order to select the proper course via the questions. Or the questions are not the correct ones...

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly trivial; all you have to do is check the values of each `select` tag, and set the `href` of the anchor accordingly.

Here's a tiny mockup:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var select = document.getElementById('language');
  var anchor = document.getElementById('next');
  
  select.onchange = function(){
    anchor.href = select.value;
  }
}
```

```html
Which is your preferred language? 
<select id="language">
  <option value="#">--------------</option>
  <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">Python</option>
  <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b">C++</option>
</select>
<br>
<a id ="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Basically, I'm listening to `onchange` on the select element, and can therefore update the link whenever the chosen option changes.

If you aren't using an `<a>` anchor tag, but something else, for the *Next* page button, you can always just check the values before redirecting the user:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var select = document.getElementById('color');
  var next = document.getElementById('next');
  
  next.onclick = function(){
    switch (select.value){
        case '1':
          window.location.href = "http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/";
          break;
        case '2':
          window.location.href = "http://www.omglasergunspewpewpew.com/";
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
What is your least favourite colour?
<select id="color">
  <option value="1">puke</option>
  <option value="2">The best color in the world!</option>
</select><br>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Basically, whatever you're doing, you can just check `select.value`, and perform an action accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the story is a little more complicated:

1. The links are fixed, i.e. they are quite complicated to write it via a "generate" function (they are something like: base_url + id_1  + base_url_2 + id_2 + base_url_3)

2. There are 6 different courses, each one with its own link:
a) regular user - in English
b) regular user - in German
c) user with access to confidential data - in English
d) user with access to confidential data - in German
e) user manager - in English
f) user manager - in German

Comment: To select the proper course, you would need to meet criteria from more than one form. I think there should be a lot of "if" statements in place in order to select the proper course via the questions. Or the questions are not the correct ones...

Comment: @SorinGeorgescu You could use a switch statement per form, checking which inputs have been selected. Then, at the end, use an if statement to grab whatever value (some variable/whatnot) to see which link should be used.

Comment: @SorinGeorgescu Look at example 2; I think it's closer to what you actually need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but for me is not as easy at it sounds. I posted a draft, and I'm also still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

first draft, not working but that's the best I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
  var language = document.getElementById('lang');
  var confidential = document.getElementById('conf');
  var manager = document.getElementById('mgr');
  var next = document.getElementById('next');

 next.onclick = function(){
 switch (true){
 case language === "isEnglish":
     window.open('link/regular_user_in_English', '_blank'); 
 break;

 case language === "isGerman":
 window.open('link/regular_user_in_German', '_blank');
 break;

 case language === "isGerman" && confidential === "isConf":
 window.open('link/conf_in_German', '_blank');
 break;

 default:    
 break;
     }
  }

 </script>

  Which language would you prefer to do the training in?
  <select id="lang">
    <option value="isEnglish">English</option>
    <option value="isGerman">German</option>
  </select><br />
  Are you a confidential data handler?
  <select id="conf">
     <option value="notConf">No</option>
     <option value="isConf">Yes</option>  
  </select><br />
  Are you a people manager?
  <select id="mgr">
    <option value="notManager">No</option>
    <option value="isManager">Yes</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <button id="next">Next</button>
```